# Time methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand how method invocation works in Ruby objects. Ruby docs list a bunch of methods to execute on ruby objects. When I try one of them

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
puts Time.new(2008,6,21, 13,30,0, "+09:00").utc.seconds_since_midnight
```

I get the following output

```
1.9.3
bin/musor.rb:14:in `<main>': undefined method `seconds_since_midnight' for 2008-06-21 13:30:00 +0900:Time (NoMethodError)
```

What's wrong with the call I make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`seconds_since_midnight` is Time extension added by rails. If you want to use it, you will need to add `require 'activesupport/core_ext'` and install activesupport gem first.